# VS2010 formatting inserts space after "empty" control flow statement

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, formatting

Visual Studio 2010 is formatting my code with a space after an "empty" control flow statement:

For example:

```
while(true) ;
```

instead of:

```
while(true);
```

Is there an option to disable this behavior?

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you use

```
while (true) { };
```

instead, which doesn't get the space added and is less likely to be misinterpreted by people reading the code.

Comment: I appreciate your suggestion. However, the syntax I use is perfectly legal. There should be an option to disable this and in any case coders shouldn't be forced to change old habits due to some UI glitch..

Comment: You might like to update your example to something less obviously an infinite loop, such as `while(DoSomething());`. I still think that `while(DoSomething()) { };` is clearer, but agree that's subjective. I can't see any options in Visual Studio for changing this type of spacing. You might get some more responses if you add a tag for the specific language you're working in.

Comment: For some reason I assumed the behavior for C/C++ would be the same as C# (I don't use VS for "native" languages) but it turns out I was wrong. Except for indentation, VS doesn't do much formatting for C\C++ at all. Anyway, I was referring to C#. Tag added. Thanks.